# How can I do multiple IF conditions in MS EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I am trying to assign multiple conditions to a cell in excel using the `IF` formula.

What I want to achieve is that if the value of cell `A` is greater than `12000`, but less than `75000`, then the operation to be performed is to multiply the value of cell `A` by `0.1`. In turn, I want that if the value of `A` is less than or equal to `1000` then the value of the cell with the formula will always be `100`.

Comment: Generally you can use `IFS` however you don't specifcally say what happens to numbers between 1000 and 12000, nor if the number is greater than 75000

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. If number is greater than 75000, the value of the cell becomes "3000" and if the number is greater than 1000 but less than 12000, the original value of cell "A" is to be multiplied by 0.1

Comment: Instead of answering in the comments [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1785781/edit) and clarify what you expect for each numbers range. But based on your last comment it seems that both 12000-75000 and also 1000-12000 should have the same output of A*0.1. Is that correct (if so why does the question say "greater than 12000")?

Comment: Could you please share us with a simple sample? It seems that your request is not clear enough. Thx~

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **nested `IF`** function. What you want to do is to at each step specify what to do *if_true*, and then *if_false* put another `IF` with the next condition.

Something like:

```
=IF(A1>75000,3000,IF(A1>12000,A1*0.1,IF(A1>1000,A1*0.1,100)))
```